# How do I actually use a Phoenix Up?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

I bought a few Phoenix Ups in anticipation that I would need one eventually. Well, in this battle, my Barbarian was killed. Because it is a major battle, I would like him to get the experience for it. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to use a Phoenix Up. It isn't present in the item list for other characters, and I can't access an item list for the Barbarian. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured out what was happening. The item list started out scrolled to the bottom, and the Phoenix Up was at the top. In order to scroll this list, you must use your mouse wheel, and there is no scroll bar. In every other list in the game, the scroll wheel doesn't work, so I didn't even try it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you may not have actually purchased the Phoenix Up or may have already used it.

Using a Phoenix Up is done by opening the potion-shaped "items" menu on any of your living characters, touching the Phoenix Up, and then touching the fallen character you wish to revive.

The descriptive text of the Phoenix Up does mention that "None of your players can use this", though it doesn't seem to have any effect on the game: I was still able to use the Phoenix Up even immediately after confirming the purchase with the "you might not be able to use this" warning.